# Error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this code for accessing the iframe in my page:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frmDownloader');
var contDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument :iframe.contentWindow.document;
contDoc.getElementById("hdnBase64Holder").value = combinedTable;
contDoc.getElementById("btnDownloadExcel").click();
```

But I'm getting an error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

Although I was able to access once. I haven't changed anything after it worked. And as I test it again I'm getting this error. Is there any work around for this?. Thanks

UPDATE - FEB 20,2014

Sorry for late reply guys.
I think I found the solution to the problem, but I think it has something to do with the visibility:hidden or display:none attribute added to the iframe tag. I don't know why it returns an error, Since I need it to be hidden. That's why I just ended up using other asp objects.

Many Thanks for the previous answers and help.
And sorry again for late reply.

Comment: Silly question: is it the iframe and its content available by the time you access `#hdnBase64Holder`?

Comment: Is your window and iframe on the same origin ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: @MarcoCI yes it is. That is why I'm having a hard time debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could execute script cross frames (XSS threat). There are some libs that offer workarounds but I doubt how long will be available as this is considered a serious security threat

Comment: This does not answer the OP question. Instead it should be a comment.

Comment: I think this is an error that cannot be fixed, but for the moment could be bypassed (not recommended). This is why I do think this *is* an answer and it is not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your code to the onload event of the iframe.